# How to write unit test for failure case of json.Marshall?

Tags: json, unit-testing, go

I have following code:

```
func policyDocumentToStr(doc map[string]interface{}) (*string, error) {
   policy, err := json.Marshal(doc)
   if err != nil {
     log.Debugf("Error converting policy document to string. Error %s", err)
     return nil, err
   }

   policyAsString := string(policy)
   return &policyAsString, nil
}
```

I want to write a unit test which would cover the case of `json.Marshal(doc)` returning an error. Can anybody suggest how can I generate an error? What kind of input to function would result in error at line `policy, err := json.Marshal(doc)`?

Comment: Amazingly, the documentation describes some conditions under which Marshal() returns an error. https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Feed it a value that cannot be represented in JSON.  There are many ways to do this, including creating a type with a custom marshaler that always returns an error. But one of the simplest ways is to try to marshal a channel:

```
x := map[string]interface{}{
    "foo": make(chan int),
}
_, err := json.Marshal(x)
fmt.Printf("Marshal error: %s\n", err)
```

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/D2qoJ_azKVk)

Answer (score 7):

Define a type that implements [json.Marshaler](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler). Use this type to produce any error you want (including error values from the json package):

```
type FakeValue struct {
    err error
}

func (v FakeValue) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if v.err != nil {
            return nil, v.err
    }

    return []byte(`null`), v.err
}

func TestPolicyString(t *testing.T) {
    doc := map[string]interface{}{
            "fake_error": FakeValue{errors.New("fail!")},
    }

    _, err := policyDocumentToStr(doc)
    if err == nil {
            t.Fatal("Got nil, want error")
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any easy way to do this for `Unmarshal`?

Comment: @ArunaHerath, in the same way, just implement the [Unmarshaler](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) interface.

Comment: but... how does policyDocumentToStr know to use this implementation?

Comment: @ztorstri, the json package checks if the interfaces json.Marshaler and/or json.Unmarshaler are implemented and uses them if possible.

Answer (score 6):

> Monkey patching is one of the ways to facilitate testing by changing a program at runtime, either by replacing a function or a variable. Here we are swapping the json.Marshal and we can mock it while testing.

```
var (
   jsonMarshal = json.Marshal
)
```

> This is your piece of code

```
func policyDocumentToStr(doc map[string]interface{}) (*string, error) {
  policy, err := jsonMarshal(doc)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Error converting policy document to string. Error %s", err)
    return nil, err
  }

  policyAsString := string(policy)
  return &policyAsString, nil
}
```

> The test code would look something like this

```
import (
    "testing"
    "errors"
)

func fakemarshal(v interface{}) ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte{}, errors.New("Marshalling failed")
}

func restoremarshal(replace func(v interface{}) ([]byte, error)) {
    jsonMarshal = replace
}

func TestPolicyDocumentToStr(t * testing.T){
    storedMarshal := jsonMarshal
    jsonMarshal = fakemarshal
    defer restoremarshal(storedMarshal)

    input := map[string]interface{} {
        "test": "test1",
    }
    tests := []struct {
        name string
        arg map[string]interface{}
        wantErr string
    }{
        {
            name: "Test if JSON Marshalling fails",
            arg: input,
            wantErr: "Marshalling failed",
        },
    }

    for _, tt := range tests {
        _, gotErr := policyDocumentToStr(tt.arg)
       if gotErr != nil && gotErr.Error() != tt.wantErr {
            t.Errorf("Expected %s but got %s", tt.wantErr, gotErr.Error())
       }
    }
}
```